How to add row for a groupby dataframe?
I have a dataframe which comes from groupby. it looks like:
                    pnl      amt
ticker        ex                
1000RATS_USDT kn    1.0    666.0
AAVE_USDT     bg   -7.4   5724.0
              gt   -1.7   2246.0
              kn   -1.0   1736.0
ARB_USDT      hb    3.6  17390.0
...                 ...      ...
XVG_USDT      gt   -4.4   4457.0
              kn   12.0   7319.0
ZEC_USDT      gt    0.4     65.0
              kn   70.8   9626.0

I want to add rows for index ex.
I know i can add row like this:
ticker_ex_df.loc[('1000RATS_USDT', 'sum')] = 0

but the outcome is:
                    pnl      amt
ticker        ex                
1000RATS_USDT kn    1.0    666.0
AAVE_USDT     bg   -7.4   5724.0
              gt   -1.7   2246.0
              kn   -1.0   1736.0
ARB_USDT      hb    3.6  17390.0
...                 ...      ...
XVG_USDT      gt   -4.4   4457.0
              kn   12.0   7319.0
ZEC_USDT      gt    0.4     65.0
              kn   70.8   9626.0
1000RATS_USDT sum   0.0      0.0

It do add row, but it adda in the last line, and not merge with the first line.
The ideal dataframe is:
                    pnl      amt
ticker        ex                
1000RATS_USDT kn    1.0    666.0
              sum   1.0    666.0
AAVE_USDT     bg   -7.4   5724.0
              gt   -1.7   2246.0
              kn   -1.0   1736.0
              sum  -10.4   ....
ARB_USDT      hb    3.6  17390.0
...                 ...      ...
XVG_USDT      gt   -4.4   4457.0
              kn   12.0   7319.0
              sum
ZEC_USDT      gt    0.4     65.0
              kn   70.8   9626.0
              sum

could you help on this? How can i add sum in the group elegantly?
